# investigate $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\alpha \ln n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to investigate the series (Hence, when the series converges and when the series converges absolutely depending on $\alpha$).

$$\sum\limits_{n\ge2}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\alpha \ln n}}$$

1. For $\alpha \gt 1$ the series converges because $a_n = \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln n}$ is monotonic sequence converges to $0$ and therefore the sum $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ converges by Leibniz criterion (Alternating series test). **Therefore, for $\alpha > 1$ the series converges and also converges absolutely.**
2. The case where $\alpha \le 1$ is unclear to me. Basically, I understood I can use the fact that $\ln n < n^b$ for sufficiently large $n$ and for all $b$.

I'd be glad if you could guide me with #2 regarding both convergence and convergence absolutely.

Thanks.

Comment: For non-absolute convergence, what changes when $\alpha \leq 1$? Think about your proof for $\alpha > 1$ and see if you can convince yourself it also works for $\alpha \leq 1$ (for $\alpha > 0$ of course!)

Comment: Do you know the theorem regarding the (absolute) convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$? If not, see if you can figure out for what values of $\alpha$ this converges for. Then, since in the limit, $\ln n < n^{\epsilon}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, you should be able to use a comparison test. See if you can fill in the remaining details.

Comment: @dorebell, for $\alpha=1$: We can compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ which diverges. Right?

Comment: The series does diverge (absolutely) at $\alpha = 1$. The easiest way to see this is the integral test (you get $\log(\log(x))$). While you can compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$, this series converges (again, the easiest way to see this is the integral test), so this isn't helpful. I don't know if there's an obvious thing to compare the series to for the $\alpha = 1$ case (someone correct me if there is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The convergence of the series**

- If $\alpha\ge0$ then by Leibniz theorem the series is convergent.
- If $\alpha<0$ then the series is divergent since the general term of this series doesn't even converge to $0$.

**The absolute convergence of the series**

- if $\alpha>1$ then the series is absolutely convergent by comparison with a convergent Riemann series:
  $$\frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln n}\le \frac{1}{n^\alpha }$$
- If $\alpha=1$ then by the integral test we see that the series isn't absolutely convergent.
- If $\alpha<1$ then the series isn't absolutely convergent  by comparison with the last case.

Comment: Thank you, I understood all, but I can't use the integral test. I know the condensation test can be an alternative, but I really want to use the hint: $\ln n < n^b$ (for all $b$ and sufficiently large $n$) .

Comment: This hint is useful for the second case of the convergence of the series.

Comment: If you assume the theorem that $\sum \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ converges absolutely iff $\alpha > 1$, then the hint helps in both directions. To show the series diverges for $\alpha < 1$, you can use this fact to apply the comparison test (compare $\frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon}\ln n}$ to $\frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon+\delta}}$ for any $\epsilon > \delta > 0$, since $\ln n < n^{\delta}$.

Comment: Thank you both dorebell  and Sami!

Comment: Nice work, @Sami!